# How to find reverse order pairs in two arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is an [interview question](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/There-are-two-arrays-A1-and-A2-Find-out-the-pairs-of-numbers-in-A2-which-were-in-reverse-order-in-A1-For-ex-A1-2-QTN_131020.htm). There are two arrays `A1` and `A2`. Find out the pairs of numbers in `A2` which were in reverse order in `A1`. For example, `A1 = [2 6 5 8 1 3]`, `A2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`. Answer: `(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (5, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6)`.

O(N^2) algorithm is trivial. Is there any better algorithm ? What  do you think ?

Comment: Why (1,3) ? doesn't look like it

Comment: O(N^2) is excellent if you have it.

Comment: @Saeed O(N^2) is brute force.

Comment: What about (1,5) and (3,5)? Are you really finding inversions, inverted according to an incomplete order defined by the array A2?

Comment: @marcog, getting two element in first array is O(n^2) and finding each pair element existance in the second array is O(N) (and O(log(n) in sorted once) so simple brute force is Omega(N^3) and more wised is Omega(N^2 log(n)) non of them are O(n^2)

Comment: @Saeed `for n1 in A1: for n2 in A1: if A1.index(n1) < A1.index(n2) != A2.index(n1) < A2.index(n2): output (n1, n2)`. Simple look-up table will make `.index` a constant-time operation.

Comment: @marcog, No lookup table is not good in this case, if non of n1 and n2 are in the A2, your lookup returns what? i.e A1.index(n1) = 1 < A2.index(n2) = 2 is true, so if your lookup returns A2.index(n1) = -1 < A2.index(n2) = -1 (false) then you will print (n1, n2) you should set some constrain before your output, but another problem exists if you have {2,3,4,5,2} what's the output of A1.index(2)???

Comment: @Saeed For numbers not in `A2`, do a check before comparing indices. For duplicates, make `.index` return a list. It changes complexity to O(N^2+M) where M is the size of `A2`.

Comment: @marcog, this is my A2 : {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,....,2} would you explain when you using what index? I can't understand your `return a list` and it's usage.

Comment: @Saeed `A2.index(2)` would return `[0, 1, 2, ..., n]` in that case.

Comment: @marcog, How to use it? how do comparison?

Comment: @Saeed Instead of doing one check inside the loop, iterate through the product of indexes for `n1` and `n2` and check those. This can be made more efficient if necessary by using binary search.

Comment: @Saeed , @marcog is creating an inverted index

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pattern like `A1 = 1111122222` and  `A2 = 2222211111`, then you'll output (N/2)<sup>4</sup> pairs. Therefore you can't do any better than O(N<sup>4</sup>) in the worst case.

Below is an O(N<sup>4</sup>) solution that handles duplicates and some numbers occurring in only one of the two lists. Note that while it is O(N<sup>4</sup>) in the worst-case, it's average case of O(N<sup>2</sup>) is far more likely, similar to the complexity of quick-sort.

```
index = {} # dictionary of lists defaulting to []
for i in 0..len(A2):
  index[A2[i]].append(i)
for i1 in 0..len(A1):
  for j1 in i+1..len(A1):
    for i2 in index[A1[i1]]:
      for j2 in index[A1[j1]]:
        if i2 != j2 and i1 < j1 != i2 < j2:
          print A1[i1], A1[j1]
```

If we relax the output format slightly to allow outputting of `(1, 2) * 7` to indicate 7 reversals, then we can do better. First zip the lists, giving `[(2, 1), (6, 2),  (5, 3), (8, 4), (1, 5), (3, 6)]` for the example. Sort the arrays using a stable sort: first using the first item in each tuple, then sort another copy of the list using the second item in the tuple. Then use an adapted merge sort like the one mentioned [here](http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=3968), but instead of counting we produce we output the inversions. This is an O(NlogN) solution.

Comment: Could you have an output-sensitive algorithm that takes o(N^2) (little-O here) time, plus time linear in the number of pairs produced?  I can't think of one, but I can't rule one out either.

Comment: @template I can't think of one either, but if I do I'll post it.

Comment: I think in your second level nested loops you saying index[A2[i1]] not index[A1[i1]]? and your second nested loops takes O(n^2) in worst case, and your algorithm will be O(n^4) in worst case.

Comment: @Saeed It's finding the indexes of `A1[i1]` in `A2`. `index[A2[i1]]` would always return a list including `i1` in it. You're right about it being O(N^) in the worst case. I missed the case where `A1 = A2 = 11111`, which while rare will cause O(N^4) performance. The thing though, is that this also made me realise the output size could also be O(N^4), e.g. for `A1 = 1111122222`, `A2 = 2222211111`. I'll edit this in. Thanks for making me re-think this!

Comment: Yes in fact it's C(2,n) * C(2,n) which is O(n^4), any solution is Omega(n^4) at least and because of this I wondered when the `OP` said O(N^2) is trivial (and because I knew you will edit your answer I didn't downvoted you :).

Comment: @Saeed I was stuck on the assumption of distinct elements for too long :)

Comment: In fact you can do it better, create pair of elements sort them by their first value in first list and sort them by their second value in second list and find similar items (and use semi merge), now you can skip the outputs with similar values and just write (2,1)*k (means k time (2,1) occurred) which is O(n^2 log n) algorithm.

Comment: @Saeed Write that up as an answer? It sounds good, so I'll upvote you.

Comment: @marcog , I have no time and should be clear if I want to answer for every one, so may be takes half an hour :) you write it if you like it, I'll upvote you:)

Comment: @Saeed Done, but one gripe: I believe this is O(NlogN). See my update to see if you agree.

Comment: @marcog, your list size is O(N^2) and this sorting takes O(N^2 log(n)) also merge runs in O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

If both arrays have same elements and A1 is a rearrange of A2(which is sorted) then we can modify Merge Sort to count number of inversions present in  A1.

http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=3968

Comment: Counting will be more efficient. Notice in that link where it says "suppose ai > bj: then all these are bigger than bj". When counting only, you can add the work out the number out of order in such a case in constant time. When finding the pairs themselves, it'll take O(number of pairs).

Comment: sorry my bad.. i have modified my answer for a special case

Comment: @Rozuur Can you explain what kind of modification is required? Would this work, if two arrays are just permutation of each other e.g A1 = [3, 2,4,1] and A2= [4,1,3,2]

Answer (score 1):

I think this algorithm is quite close to the best one. If we discard the computational cost of building the trie ( n^2 assignement), we are left with a cost of n(n-1)/2 operations. It somehow uses a trie to make the pair checking cost constant. If needed, you can, at the cost of len(a)+len(b), scan the two arrays and infer what is MAX :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define MAX 9
#define AEL 6
#define BEL 6

int main(){
    int b[BEL] = {2,6,5,8,1,3};
    int a[AEL] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int **trie = calloc(MAX,sizeof(int*));
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        trie[i] = calloc(MAX,sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < AEL; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < AEL; j++){
            trie[a[i]][a[j]] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < BEL; i++ ){
        for(j = i+1; j < BEL ; j++){
            if(trie[b[j]][b[i]]){
                printf("(%d %d) ",b[j],b[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```